# How can I prevent the user to login into Docker Terminal

Tags: docker, authentication, kubernetes, security

We are planning to deploy our apps into the user env. and we need to prevent the user can't accessing the docker image terminal access, since we are using the Python app and all the required files are inside of the image, so can we set thr terminal access password or block the terminal access at all?

Docker terminal access block or setup terminal authentication

Comment: You can remove `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` command links and maybe all `/bin/*` commands in user-deployed container (in build stage of course). Be aware you can't do that if your application use these shell commands.

Comment: You can't prevent a user from `docker exec` into the container; or `docker run` the container with an interactive shell as its main command; or `docker cp` the embedded code out; or `docker export` it to a tar file.  Since the user can trivially `docker run` a container with root access to the entire host filesystem, they could copy the raw files out of Docker's internal storage if they were motivated.